# Why is this CSS rule not being hit?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a little exception visualizer that works with nested exceptions. It's rendering nicely, except for one thing:

```
.validation-summary-errors span.exception-messsage {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

The above CSS rule is not being applied. Any idea why?

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cabichandani/yF7KP/2/

**Update: I'd be embarrassed if it weren't for the fact that I am SO DELIGHTED to have this fixed. The extra "s" evaded me for maybe a half hour!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `meSSSage` to `meSSage` :

```
.validation-summary-errors span.exception-messsage
```

to

```
.validation-summary-errors span.exception-message
```

Comment: YES!!! I knew it had to be simple. I stared and stared and stared. I just could not see this. It was simply invisible to me.

Comment: Was it completely obvious to you, or did it take a bit of time? I seriously wonder if I have some kind of disability because this happens too often :)

Comment: A good IDE would point that out for you (That the class exception-messsage does not exit). I recommend PhpStorm, I've been using it for quite a while and it's awesome.

Comment: Also as a rule of thumb. When you start making errors like those, and not see them in a manner of minutes, it's usually time to hit the bed.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 with ReSharper 6.1, and it does point these things out, but the code is generated programmatically so it misses it in this case. Still, your recommendation is good. I can probably find a way to make these components in such a way that my IDE can do a better job helping me, through using templates for example.

Comment: This kind of stuff happens to everyone from time to time, so no disabilities here :)

Answer (score 2):

Extra s.

exception-message vs exception-mess**s**age

Answer (score 2):

Three 's' in message in your stylesheet, your html isn't pointing to the correct class/your css class is named incorrectly in reference to your html!

```
.validation-summary-errors span.exception-messsage {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```